# Crashed when creating a partition - now missing drive space!

Tags: macos, disk-utility, ssd, partition, core-storage

Just a couple of hours ago, while I was taking a GNU course, I decided to create a partition on my SSD to have ubuntu installed, meanwhile the disk utility was doing that, suddenly it just crashed and restarted itself, leaving 5GB free from any partition, I used `diskutil list` and this is the info it provided me:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +115.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 3B12580F-53CE-4FE2-A806-FB80AB07DD82
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

There is no additional partition on the disk utility and I was wondering if it is possible to recover this space.

My Mac is a MacBook Pro 13" Retina (Early 2015) 128 GB SSD

Answer (score 3):

In fact there isn't any space free on your disk in the sense of unallocated disk space. But you probably resized the Logical Volume *Macintosh HD* (disk1) residing in the Logical Volume Group *Macintosh HD* (disk0s2).

To expand the Logical Volume *Macintosh HD* to the full available size you have to use an undocumented command: `diskutil cs resizeVolume UUID size`.

1. Boot to your Recovery HD by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting.
2. Open in the menubar Utilities->Terminal
3. Enter `diskutil cs list` to get a list of all CoreStorage items.
4. Enter `diskutil cs unlockVolume LVUUID` (LVUUID is the UUID of the Logical Volume, usually it's the last UUID in the list you got earlier) to unlock the encrypted Logical Volume *Macintosh HD*. You have to enter the FileVault passphrase now.
5. Enter `diskutil cs resizeVolume LVUUID 0g` (0g is a magical number here - it will expand the Logical Volume to the whole available size of the LVG).
6. Enter `exit` and quit Terminal
7. Reboot to your main volume

Comment: Hi, after repeated attempts to follow step by step each of the above steps, I get an operation error code 69674, it says that the size on my storage device is different and suggests a scan/repair immediately!

Comment: @DavidM Then your LVG/LV got corrupted. Boot to the main volume and make a backup (e.g. with Time Machine) and then boot to your Recovery HD and try to repair it.

Comment: So, thats more like a hard reset on my ssd? I'll make the backup and go through it, I really appreciate your time, TYVM