# Lost space on hard disk after partitioning

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have a iMac 27" Late 2013 with 3TB Fusion Drive running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3.

I want to install Windows 10 through Bootcamp but it always hangs on partitioning the hard disk after I choosing the partition size for Windows in Boot Camp.

I tried to partition the hard disk using Disk Utility in macOS and it hangs as well. Now I have lost 1TB of space on my hard disk. I have chosen MS-Dos (FAT) as the file system during partitioning.

Below are some observations:

**diskutil list**:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            3.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk3
   1:               Windows_NTFS                         3.0 TB     disk3s1

/dev/disk5 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +2.0 TB     disk5
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2, disk0s2
                                 05DBAD36-6E3F-4C5F-8C2E-CBE7F366ED4C
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +81.8 MB    disk6
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk6s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Disk Drill 3.5.882 b... 81.8 MB    disk6s2
```

**diskutil cs list:**

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group D4D89768-822B-407C-976F-A5EC4ED51129
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         3120071938048 B (3.1 TB)
    Free Space:   1111285788672 B (1.1 TB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume A0A26722-1606-4C76-95F8-3211452A640F
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume DD4D82EB-A204-4AB1-AB56-934AE83112D8
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     1887797399552 B (1.9 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 7C4901F1-96BA-44B2-B72D-083906D4962A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 05DBAD36-6E3F-4C5F-8C2E-CBE7F366ED4C
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk5
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          2002599280640 B (2.0 TB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

How do I reclaim the lost 1 TB of disk space.

Comment: Related: [Crashed when creating a partition - now missing drive space!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218076/crashed-when-creating-a-partition-now-missing-drive-space). The magic size (0g) may be different in High Sierra. Try to verify and repair disks and volumes first!

Comment: i also got error: 69674. when i boot into recovery and make first aid it says that my storage space is different and i should repair the whole storage.i have no option to "repair". what else can i do.